# Deleting headers of various lengths in r

Tags: r

I am working to combine multiple .txt files, using the read.fwf function. My issue is that each text file is preceded by several header lines, varying from 23-28 lines before the data actually start. I want to somehow delete the first n rows in the file, so that all I am importing and combing are the data themselves.

Does anyone have any clues on how to do this? The start of each data file will be the same ("01Jan") followed by a year. I basically want to delete everything before 01Jan in the file.

Right now, my code looks like:

```
for (i in 1:length(files.x)){
  if (!exists("X")){
  X<-read.fwf(files.x[i], c(11,5, 16), header=FALSE, skip=23, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  X<-head(X, -1) #delete the last row of each table
  names(X)<-c("Date", "Time", "Data")
} else if (exists("X")){
  temp_X<-read.fwf(files.x[i], c(11,5,16), header=FALSE, skip=23,   stringsAsFactors=FALSE) #read in fixed width file
 temp_X<-head(temp_X, -1)
 names(temp_X)<-c("Date", "Time", "Data")
 X<-rbind(X, temp_X)
```

}
}

I need the skip=23 to vary according to the file being read in. Any ideas other than manually reading in each file and then combining?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
 hdr <- readLines(files.x[i],n=50) ## or some reasonable upper bound
 firstLine <- grep("^01Jan",hdr)[1]
 X <- read.fwf(files.x[i], skip=firstLine-1, ...)
```

Also, it would be more efficient to read in all the files via `fileList <- lapply(files.x,getFile)` (where `getFile` is a little utility function you write to encapsulate the logic of reading in a single file) and then `do.call(rbind,fileList)`